# is COM's IUnknown useless with the advent of unique_ptr and shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, winapi, com

Is there any reason to use COM's IUnknown interface in C++11 or later ?

AFAIK COM was created as sort of a better C++98, does C++11 make COM obsolete?

Am I right that after C++11 the majority of COM code is legacy?

Comment: COM predates C++98, and COM is usable in C and other C-compatible languages.  `IUnknown` has NOTHING to do with C++'s object lifetime management, which are what `unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr` manage. You are comparing apples and kumquats. Perhaps you are confused because `IUnknown` provides reference-counting semantics to COM objects, and `shared_ptr` provides reference-counting to C++ objects? They are very different architectures.

Comment: They're really pretty much unrelated. Among other things, COM is language-independent so you can (for example) write a COM server in C++ that you can consume from VB or C#. To the extent COM code becomes legacy, it will be when/if Microsoft changes the OS to use something else, not because of changes in C++.

Comment: @RemyLebeau what do you mean by it has nothing to do with objects lifetime management? Isn't that what IUnknown::AddRef and Release are for?

Comment: @IRP_HANDLER I said `IUnknown` has nothing to do with **C++'s** lifetime management.

Comment: You're making a confusion, COM is at its root a runtime binary contract for reusing components, it's not about source code. It's language and platform independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are completely orthogonal, they simply solve completely different problems.

COM's IUnknown provides a base interface from which other interfaces implemented by an object can be discovered.

The C++ standard library's std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr solve the problem of managing object lifetimes but do not provide any mechanism for discovering what functionality an object offers. COM enables inter-language object interop, a means for an interface to be published in one language and consumed from another.

Note that there are better wrappers for COM objects than std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr, such as ATL's CComPtr, MSVC's built-in _com_ptr_t and also one from UWP that I forget the name of.

Comment: can't IUnknown's QueryInterface be replaced with dynamic_cast?

Comment: _"and also one from UWP that I forget the name of"_ -- I think you mean `winrt::com_ptr` from C++/WinRT.

Comment: @IRP_HANDLER: Not entirely, as dynamic_cast is purely a C++ thing, where IUnknown is meant to be usable across languages. dynamic_cast wouldn't even necessarily be safe across different versions of the same compiler, let alone compilers from different vendors. IUnknown, on the other hand, should be safe regardless of compiler version, though while it relies on some type information, it is far less than the full information used by dynamic_cast.

Comment: There are two common smart pointer types for the Windows Runtime: WRL's [`ComPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/comptr-class) and C++/WinRT's [`com_ptr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/com-ptr). The Windows Runtime is not to be confused with the Universal Windows Platform.